# PHP: Notice: Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset

Tags: php, cakephp

I get this error message

```
Notice: Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 39
```

quite often on this line:

```
if(isset($getCity) && !empty($getCity)) $city = '/'.Inflector::slug($getCity[$this->request->params['named']['city']]); else $city = '';
```

I tried to understand why I get this message and added a debug log

```
CakeLog::write('activity', 'getCity '.print_r($getCity, true).'===>'.$this->request->params['named']['city'] );
```

The log file output looks always like this:

```
Activity: getCity {"39":"Montuiri"}===>39
```

what tells me that 
`$getCity` is an array with a `result => {"39":"Montuiri"}`
and `$this->request->params['named']['city']` is not empty and has a `value => 39`

So what is causing the notice message? I really don't get it how to solve that, as those messages a write my debug logs full every day...

Comment: Do a var_dump instead of print_r when debugging. The notice says about _string_ offset. Try typecasting it to integer

Comment: Try to leverage "modern" CakePHP features instead of avoiding it. Dont' use named params, use query strings and query() access to it. If you must use named params, check on the existance first: `!empty($this->request->params['named']['city'])` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the construct `$foobar[15]` to arrays and strings. When it's an array, it returns the array element with the index `15`, if it's a string, it returns the letter at the requested numerical position (16th in this case, because counting starts at zero).

If you get the message “uninitialized … offset”, it means that you're requesting a part of an array or string that doesn't exist.

Although, according to the log output, `$getCity` is an array, the PHP error message clearly indicates that at some point you are trying to access the 40th letter of a string.

It may be that the code has a branch/loop where an array variable is overwritten as string and then runs through the above line again, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error would occur if any of the following variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays.

try this i'm no sure it's work for you or not but try this

```
   if(is_array($getCity) && !empty($getCity)) 
   {
    $city = '/'.Inflector::slug($getCity[$this->request->params['named'] 
    ['city']]); else $city = '';
   }
```